# Transit visa for F 1 student back from India to US via London

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas

I have a question and a concern regarding transit visa requirement for Indian Citizen travelling back to US via London while on F 1 Visa. I have one semester left and I am visiting my family this winter. I will be coming back on 19th of January from New Delhi to Boston via London. I have visited UK's official website but I am not clear with conditions for Transit visa considering that I have a connecting flights with same airline (landing on LHR on 19th January at 5:40 pm and schedule to take off on 20th January at 9:20 am). It would be great If somebody here can comment on this and provide me with some detailed information about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [the GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes), you cannot stay in the transit area of the airport overnight (you will Need to enter the UK), but do **not** need a visa.

At UK border control, present your passport open at the visa page, completed landing card and connecting boarding pass to Boston, and you can stay until 23:59 the next day.